# selfextracting archive with 7zip via cmd.exe

Tags: compression, command-line, 7-zip, self-extracting

I downloaded 7za.exe and did this to compress a file.exe:

```
7za.rar a -mx9 archive file.exe
```

Now I want to create a selfextracting archive (.exe), so I tried this:

```
7za.rar a -mx9 -sfx archive file.exe
```

But I get the following error message:

> can't find specified sfx module

Can anyone please tell me how to make a selfextracting .exe with 7zip via cmd.exe? Thanks!

Comment: http://lists.pld-linux.org/mailman/pipermail/pld-devel-en/2006-May/017561.html

Answer (score 3):

Try [7z.sfx](http://www.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/sfx.htm):

```
7za.rar a -mx9 -sfx 7z.sfx archive file.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Another left-of-field answer is to use [AXcrypt](http://www.axantum.com/axcrypt/features.html), which not only compresses and encrypts but also supports self-executing files and has command line options.